# Passing Data between 2 Beans JSF

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

Hello im trying to build a Login Bean session. After a successful login i either get a Student or a Professor back from my database. After i get one of these i want to get to the next Page and have either a Student UI or a Professor UI to work with. But how do i get the Object to the second Page which is getting managed by an extra Bean session? Im not sure how do to it. Here some code that might explain my Issue better.

```
@Named("login")
@Stateless
public class LoginManager implements Serializable {

 @Inject
 private Login login;

 private Professor professor;
 private Student student;

 public String userLogin(Login login) {
        // Just some example code
        if (login.successful()) {
            professor = professorFromDB();
            if (professor != null) {
                return "ProfessorView";
            } else {
                Student = studentFromDB();
                if (student != null) {
                    return "StudentView";
                }
            }
        }
        return "FalseLogin";
    }

// Then all the getter setter 

}
```

```
@Named("professor")
@Stateless
public class ProfessorManager implements Serializable{

 private Professor professor;

// getter & setter
}
```

So how do i get the Object i got from the DB in my LoginManager to my ProfessorManager ? 
If something is not clear i can provide more information but i believe this should be enough to understand my question.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I dont have a faces-config.xml file since i didnt need yet.

Comment: I think you have bigger problems. What if a professor and student log on at the same time?

Comment: Thats not gonna happen its for an university project :)

Comment: Ah, in that case it's OK to have a bad design...

Answer (score 0):

OK solved it.
I added @Inject LoginManager loginManager; and took the professor from there. Didn't expect it to be this simple. :)

```
@Named("professor")
@Stateless
public class ProfessorManager implements Serializable{

 @Inject
 private LoginManager loginManager;
 private Professor professor;

@PostConstruct
 public void init(){
   this.professor = loginManager.getProfessor();

 }


// getter & setter
}
```